# How to connect aws dynamodb from nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using `aws-sdk` to connect with dynamod and i tried the following ways to connect with dynamodb.

### Method 1

```js
const aws_remote_config = {
      accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
      region: process.env.REGION,
}

express.Router().get("/test",(req,res)=>{
    AWS.config.update(aws_remote_config);
    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    const params = {
        TableName: "test"
    };
    docClient.scan(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            //console.log(err)
            res.send({
                success: false,
                message: err
            });
        } else {
            const { Items } = data;
            res.send({
                success: true,
                movies: Items
            });
        }
    });

})
```

I am getting this response

```js
{"success":false,"message":{"message":"Requested resource not found","code":"ResourceNotFoundException","time":"2021-01-27T07:43:55.351Z","requestId":"L2MNQCL2EKUM13QED03FMK3ADJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG","statusCode":400,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":14.298055549242983}}
```

### Method 2

```js
const aws_remote_config = {
      accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
      region: process.env.REGION,
}

express.Router().get("/test",(req,res)=>{
    AWS.config.update(aws_remote_config);
    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    const params = {
        TableName: "test"
    };
    var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
     var param = {}
    dynamodb.listTables(param, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log("Sussess data",data);     
    });
})
```

I got this

```js
Sussess data { TableNames: [] }
```

### Method 3

```js
// i tried to connect like this

AWS.config.loadFromPath('../../config/db.json');
// path is correct, i checked by console.log(require('../../config/db.json'));
```

I got this

```js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../config/db.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
    at Object.readFileSync (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\merchent-backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\util.js:95:26)
    at Config.loadFromPath (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\merchent-backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:473:39)
    at C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\merchent-backend\routes\user\test.js:9:16
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\merchent-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\merchent-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\merchent-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\merchent-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\merchent-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

Comment: I just saw that someone downvoted my question, please mention the region.

Comment: #1 fails because there is no table named `test` in the region indicated by `process.env.REGION`. #3 seems fairly self-evident: there's no file at `../../config/db.json`.

Comment: `here's no file at ../../config/db.json` as i mentioned `path is correct, i checked by console.log(require('../../config/db.json'));`

Comment: The require statement has different rules about path. Instead of the relative path, you might also try absolute, for example: `process.cwd() + ‘/config/db.json’` (and add `../` as necessary once you know what `process.cwd()` is). And use `fs.existsSync(...)` to check that you have the correct path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with another answer:  Method #2 appears to be working.  One point is that `listTables` does not require any arguments to succeed.  Of the two arguments ...

- `Limit` is optional; it defaults to 100
- `ExclusiveStartTableName` is also optional.  It should only be provided if you are "paging" through a long list of table names and need to get the next page.

Long story short, this ...

```
Sussess data { TableNames: [] }
```

... is showing that the account you are authenticated in does not have any DynamoDB tables.  So the array of table names is empty.